# Модели и контроллер в mvc и выдаваемая ошибка?

Tags: entity-framework, mvc

Пытаюсь связать свою модель с контроллером и получаю вот такую ошибку.

> User::EntityType 'User' has no key defined. Define the key for this
>   EntityType.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В официальной документации microsoft написано следующее:

> (If you get an error, you probably didn't build the application before starting adding the controller.)

С MVC - только знакомлюсь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это ошибка не mvc, это чисто EF'ная. Покажите ваши классы, у вас похоже просто нет первичного ключа -- согласно конвенции для User это должно быть поле ID или UserId (я предпочитаю ID везде делать)

Подробнее скажем тут: http://andrey.moveax.ru/post/mvc3-in-depth-entity-framework-03-code-first-conventions

> Первичный ключ таблицы
>
> Свойства с именем Id или <имя класса>Id считается первичным ключом
>   создаваемой таблицы. При этом регистр символов не учитывается

Можно просто создать поле:

```
public class User
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Можно явно указать атрибут `[Key]` (это необязательно в случае если у вас имя дано по стандартным соглашениям):

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```